# Выпадающее меню верстка

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на каждый из этих элементов (ссылок) должно открываться выпадающее меню. Тоесть выпадающие меню  должно быть поверх следующих ссылок.

Comment: какие варианты решения?

Answer (score 3):

Например на CSS

```html
<style>
/* Style The Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
</style>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown A</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link A1</a>
    <a href="#">Link A2</a>
    <a href="#">Link A3</a>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown B</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link B1</a>
    <a href="#">Link B2</a>
    <a href="#">Link B3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```